# How to add X-Total-Count to header response in Rocket Rust REST API?

Tags: rust, react-admin, rust-rocket

I create a REST API with Rust and [Rocket](https://rocket.rs/) that works with swagger.
Now I'm trying to consumes this API with React [react-admin](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/) to be precise. Everything works OK until I need to call a list where the famous X-Total-Count problem appears, and I am not able to solve it, probably due to lack of experience with Rust.

This is the message
"**The X-Total-Count header is missing in the HTTP Response**. The jsonServer Data Provider expects responses for lists of resources to contain this header with the total number of results to build the pagination. If you are using CORS, did you declare X-Total-Count in the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header"

This is my response header

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Server: Rocket
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: x-total-count, content-length, server
Content-Length: 45
Date: Wed, 02 Jun 2021 04:38:21 GMT
```

I tried a lot of things, to append in the header the X-Total-Count: cant_registries with out any lucky

This is my main.rs. Any hint, help, modification is welcome. Thanks in advance

```
#![feature(proc_macro_hygiene, decl_macro)]

#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket;
#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket_okapi;

use rocket::request::Request;
use rocket::response::{self, Response, Responder};
use rocket::http::ContentType;
use rocket::http::Header;

use rocket::request::{Form, FromForm};
use rocket_contrib::json::Json;
use rocket_okapi::swagger_ui::*;
use schemars::JsonSchema;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

use rocket::http::Method;
use std::env;
use std::process::Command;
use rocket_cors::{
    AllowedOrigins,
    Cors, CorsOptions,
};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, JsonSchema)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
struct User {
    user_id: u64,
    username: String
}

// impl<'r> Responder<'r> for User {
//    fn respond_to(self, _: &Request) -> response::Result<'r> {
//        Response::build()
//            .header(Header::new("X-Total-Count", "1"))
//            .ok()
//    }
// }

fn example_email() -> &'static str {
    "test@example.com"
}

fn make_cors() -> Cors {
    let allowed_origins = AllowedOrigins::some_exact(&[
        "http://localhost:3000",
    ]);

    CorsOptions { // 5.
        allowed_origins,
        expose_headers: [ "x-total-count", "content-length","server" ]
        .iter()
            .map(ToString::to_string)
            .collect(), 
        allowed_methods: vec![Method::Get, Method::Post, Method::Patch].into_iter().map(From::from).collect(),
        allow_credentials: false,
        ..Default::default()
    }
        .to_cors()
        .expect("error while building CORS")
}

/// # Get all users
#[openapi]
#[get("/user")]
fn get_all_users() -> Json<Vec<User>> {
    Json(vec![User {
        user_id: 88,
        username: "goja288".to_owned(),
    }])
    

}

fn main() {
    rocket::ignite()
        .mount(
            "/",
            routes_with_openapi![
                get_all_users,
            ],
        )
        .mount(
            "/swagger-ui/",
            make_swagger_ui(&SwaggerUIConfig {
                url: "../openapi.json".to_owned(),
                ..Default::default()
            }),
        ).attach(make_cors())
        .launch();
}
```

Comment: Well, is the `X-Total-Count` header in the response *at all*? You might need to add it manually. Being allowed by CORS does nothing if the header is not present in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @OleksiiFilonenko for the answer. Exactly, the reality is that I am not quite understanding how to add it. I try various things. Now I am reading the [documentation](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.4/rocket/response/trait.Responder.html) again to see if I can achieve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a header to the response by wrapping `Json<Vec<User>>` (that implement [`Responder`](https://docs.rs/rocket/latest/rocket/response/trait.Responder.html) trait) with a custom struct (see [Rocket docs on custom responders](https://rocket.rs/v0.4/guide/responses/#custom-responders):

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct JsonWithTotalCount<T: Serialize> {
    data: Json<Vec<T>>,
    total_count_header: Header<'static>,
}

impl<T: Serialize> JsonWithTotalCount<T> {
    pub fn new(data: Vec<T>) -> Self {
        Self {
            total_count_header: Header::new("X-Total-Count", data.len().to_string()),
            data: Json(data),
        }
    }
}

impl<'r, T: Serialize> Responder<'r> for JsonWithTotalCount<T> {
    fn respond_to(self, request: &Request) -> response::Result<'r> {
        let mut build = Response::build();
        build.merge(self.data.respond_to(request)?);
        build.header(self.total_count_header);
        build.ok()
    }
}
```

And use it in your `get_all_users` function:

```
/// # Get all users
#[get("/user")]
fn get_all_users() -> JsonWithTotalCount<User> {
    JsonWithTotalCount::new(vec![User {
        user_id: 88,
        username: "goja288".to_owned(),
    }])
}
```

Comment: As a sidenote, Rocket makes it *really hard* to add headers to arbitrary responses. [`actix-web`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/dev/struct.HttpResponseBuilder.html#method.header) makes it a bit easier.

Comment: Amazing @Oleskii with that code works it if i remove openapi. Thanks! Now I need to figure out how to use with openapi (the trait `OpenApiResponder<'_>` is not implemented for `JsonWithTotalCount<User>`), but that's another problem :D. I will check actix-web